# Fijar columnas en Datatables html5- js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Deseo fijar algunas columnas en una tabla hecha con Datatable. Sin embargo cuando utilizo la propiedad `fixedColumns` lo único que hace es duplicar el número de columnas que se especifica, pero lo pone encima de las otras, por lo que se superponen.

Adjunto el código:

```js
 $("#reporte").DataTable({
   dom: 'Bfrtip',
   buttons: [
     $.extend(true, {}, buttonCommon, {
       extend: 'excelHtml5',
       className: 'btn btn-option',
       text: '<i class="fa fa-table marginExcel"></i><br> Exportar',
       container: '#optionExcel'
     })
   ],
   bFilter: false,
   bInfo: false,
   bLengthChange: false,
   bPaginate: false,
   'oLanguage': {
     'sZeroRecords': false,
     'sEmptyTable': false
   },
   scrollY: 200,
   scrollX: true,
   scrollCollapse: true,
   scrollXInner: '100%',
   fixedColumns: {
     leftColumns: 0,
     rightColumns: 0,
   }
 });
 $("#tblReport").css({
   'width': '100%'
 });
 }
```

¿Como puedo corregirlo?

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir el código que tienes hasta el momento?

Comment: https://datatables.net/examples/index

Comment: A que te refieres con "fijar"? hacerlas de un ancho fijo? que siempre muestren unos datos concretos?...¿?

Answer (score 3):

Tenia el mismo problema que tu, como muestro en el primer ejemplo:

**Ejemplo `dataTable` con columnas fijas desalineadas**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        scrollY:        "160px",
        scrollX:        true,
        scrollCollapse: true,
        paging:         false,
        fixedColumns:   {
            leftColumns: 2//Le indico que deje fijas solo las 2 primeras columnas
        },
         "footerCallback": function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {
            var api = this.api(), data;
 
            // Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
            var intVal = function ( i ) {
                return typeof i === 'string' ?
                    i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '')*1 :
                    typeof i === 'number' ?
                        i : 0;
            };
 
            //4 Indica la columna que sera filtrada

            // Total over all pages
            total = api
                .column( 4 )
                .data()
                .reduce( function (a, b) {
                    return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                }, 0 );
 
            // Total over this page
            pageTotal = api
                .column( 4, { page: 'current'} )
                .data()
                .reduce( function (a, b) {
                    return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                }, 0 );
 
            // Update footer
            $( api.column( 4 ).footer() ).html(
                '$'+pageTotal +' ( $'+ total +' total)'
            );
        }
    } );
} );
```

```html
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.2.2/js/dataTables.fixedColumns.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.2.2/css/fixedColumns.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table id="example" class="table-bordered table-striped ">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2">Id</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Producto</th>
      <th colspan="6" style="text-align:center">Ventas</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Ene</th>
      <th>Feb</th>
      <th>Mar</th>
      <th>Abr</th>
      <th>May</th>
      <th>Jun</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td><td>Producto 1</td>
      <td>5</td><td>5</td><td>5</td>
      <td>5</td><td>5</td><td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td><td>Producto 2</td>
      <td>50</td><td>54</td><td>5</td>
      <td>5</td><td>87</td><td>56</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td><td>Producto 3</td>
      <td>6</td><td>6</td><td>8</td>
      <td>5</td><td>3</td><td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td><td>Producto 4</td>
      <td>6</td><td>6</td><td>6</td>
      <td>5</td><td>6</td><td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td><td>Producto 5</td>
      <td>6</td><td>6</td><td>6</td>
      <td>5</td><td>6</td><td>8</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="4" style="text-align:right">Total:</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
</table>
```

**Ejemplo `dataTable` con columnas fijas truco para alinearlas**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo único que hice fue poner un `div` con un tamaño fijo en el cabecero.

```
<th rowspan="2">
   <div style="width:200px!Important;">
      Producto
   </div>
</th>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        scrollY:        "160px",
        scrollX:        true,
        scrollCollapse: true,
        paging:         false,
        fixedColumns:   {
            leftColumns: 2//Le indico que deje fijas solo las 2 primeras columnas
        }
    } );
} );
```

```html
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.2.2/js/dataTables.fixedColumns.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.2.2/css/fixedColumns.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table id="example" class="table-bordered table-striped ">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2">Id</th>
      <th rowspan="2">
        <div style="width:200px!Important;">
          Producto
        </div>
      </th>
      <th colspan="6" style="text-align:center">Ventas</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Ene</th>
      <th>Feb</th>
      <th>Mar</th>
      <th>Abr</th>
      <th>May</th>
      <th>Jun</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td><td>Producto 1</td>
      <td>5</td><td>5</td><td>5</td>
      <td>5</td><td>5</td><td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td><td>Producto 2</td>
      <td>50</td><td>54</td><td>5</td>
      <td>5</td><td>87</td><td>56</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td><td>Producto 3</td>
      <td>6</td><td>6</td><td>8</td>
      <td>5</td><td>3</td><td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td><td>Producto 4</td>
      <td>6</td><td>6</td><td>6</td>
      <td>5</td><td>6</td><td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td><td>Producto 5</td>
      <td>6</td><td>6</td><td>6</td>
      <td>5</td><td>6</td><td>8</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.  Saludos.

Comment: muy buena respuesta

Comment: Muchas Gracias :-)

Comment: @Cristina Carrasco Angulo  Como podría Hacer la suma de los productos vendidos según el código, en mi caso lo que quiero sumar son los salarios , pero quiero tomar de idea tu respuesta

Comment: @MarcoEufragio checa la edicion que hice, lo saque de aqui https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/footer_callback.html, espero que te sea de utilidad

Answer (score 0):

yo utilizo esto que en una versión obsoleta de este plugin se utilizo y hasta ahora se sigue utilizando pero creo se cambio el nombre de la definicion a [`columnDefs`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs), actualmente yo lo uso con `aoColumns` y no me da problemas

```
 $("#reporte").DataTable({
  ...,
  "aoColumns": [
    { "width": "15%", "title": "Descripcion", "bSortable": true },
    { "width": "16%", "title": "Lugar", "bSortable": true },
    { "width": "21%", "title": "Fecha", "bSortable": true },
    { "width": "18%", "title": "Cliente (s)", "bSortable": true },
    { "title": "Usuario (s)", "bSortable": true },
    { "title": "Estado", "bSortable": true }
  ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

yo tenia el mismo problema pero lo pude arreglar de una manera muy eficiente con tan solo unas lineas de codigo, al crear la tabla simplemente agrega esta propiedad a la DataTable():

```
$('#tabla').DataTable({
initComplete: function(settings, json) {
            setTimeout(function() { $("#tabla").DataTable.draw(); }, 200);
        }
}).draw();
```

lo que hara esto es que al finalizar la carga de tu tabla lanzara un time out de 200 milisegundos que hara que la tabla se refresque y se muestre correctamente.

Answer (score 0):

el problema es que no estas haciendo el export correcto del css del datatables fixedcolumns.
la solución es que veas que versión estas manejando del fixedcolumns.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.2.2/js/dataTables.fixedColumns.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.2.2/css/fixedColumns.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```