# Mantener la primera columna siempre visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap, datatables, bootstrap-4

Dispongo de una tabla que mantenía las dos primeras columnas visibles y con scroll lateral, pero al momento de cambiar a bootstrap 4 ha perdido esas propiedades, he intentado solucionarlo añadiendo las librerías dedicadas a este nuevo bootstrap, pero sin ningún resultado satisfactorio.

Partiendo de [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/41959/fijar-columnas-en-datatables-html5-js), logré que en bootstrap 3 funcionase, pero al migrarlo al 4 ha dejado de funcionar, dejo un ejemplo con el problema en [este fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2z9L5ey7/5/).

```
$('#tablaDatos').DataTable({
    "data": datos,
    "bDestroy": true,
    "language": {
        "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.16/i18n/Spanish.json"
    }, select: false,
    "iDisplayLength": 10,
    "columns": columnas,
    "columnDefs": [
         { className: "hide", "targets": [0] },
         { width: 200, targets: 1 }
    ],
    "fnDrawCallback": function (oSettings) {
        runAllCharts();
    },
    //Esto es lo que ha dejado de funcionar
    scrollY: "35em",
    scrollX: true,
    scrollCollapse: true,
    paging: false,
    fixedColumns: {
        leftColumns: 2
    },
    //Fin problema
    rowCallback: function (row, data, index) {
    $.each($(row).find('td'), function (ind, val) {
        if (ind != 0) {
            let fila = $(row).find('td:eq(' + ind + ')').contents()[0].nodeValue;
            if (fila == 0) {
                $(row).find('td:eq(' + ind + ')').html('<div></div>');
                $(row).find('td:eq(' + ind + ')').css('background-color', '#b9b7b7');
            } else if(fila > 0){
                $(row).find('td:eq(' + ind + ')').html('<div class="text-center encontrar"><i class="fa fa-clipboard-list fa-3x" style="color:#107A00;"></div>');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

});

Comment: Ya revisaste esto? https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/examples/styling/bootstrap4.html

Comment: Gracias, ya encontré una solución, aun no he tenido tiempo de escribir la respuesta, pero te dejo el [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/359xp048/1/)