# Primera columna fija al hacer scroll horizontal

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Estoy haciendo una tabla con divs usando bootstrap, mi problema es el siguiente, necesito que la "tabla" haga un scroll horizontal conforme no se vea mas información, pero la primera columna se quede fija.

```css
div.table.prueba {
  overflow-x: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <div class="table-prueba">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">Columna1</div>
                <div class="col">Columna2</div>
                <div class="col">Columna3</div>
                <div class="col">Columna4</div>
                <div class="col">Columna5</div>
                <div class="col">Columna6</div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

No tengo la posibilidad de hacerlo en  a ver si alguien puede hecharme una mano! gracias!!

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/41959/fijar-columnas-en-datatables-html5-js                aca te dejo un enlace donde hay solucion a este problema, saludos

Comment: @CarlosLópez esta respuesta, si bien podría ayudar, hace uso de la librería datatables.js

Answer (score 1):

Acá hay una solución que podría ayudarte:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="pinned">Pin</th>
                <th>Cabecera</th>
                <th>Cabecera</th>
                <th>Cabecera</th>
                <th>Cabecera</th>
                <th>Cabecera</th>
                <th>Cabecera</th>
                <th>Cabecera</th>
                <th>Cabecera</th>
                <th>Cabecera</th>
                <th>Cabecera</th>
                <th>Cabecera</th>
                <th>Cabecera</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="pinned">Pinned 1</td>
                <td>Celda</td>
                <td>Celda</td>
                <td>Celda</td>
                <td>Celda</td>
                <td>Celda</td>
                <td>Celda</td>
                <td>Celda</td>
                <td>Celda</td>
                <td>Celda</td>
                <td>Celda</td>
                <td>Celda</td>
                <td>Celda</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="pinned">Pinned 2</td>
                <td>Celda</td>
                <td>Celda</td>
                <td>Celda</td>
                <td>Celda</td>
                <td>Celda</td>
                <td>Celda</td>
                <td>Celda</td>
                <td>Celda</td>
                <td>Celda</td>
                <td>Celda</td>
                <td>Celda</td>
                <td>Celda</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Y en tu archivo de estilos.css

```
th, td {
    white-space: nowrap;}
.pinned {
    position: absolute;
    width: 5em;
    margin-left: -5em;}
.table-responsive {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;}
```

Cambié tu "table" dado que estabas utilizando divs y personalmente considero más sencillo utilizar los "th" de toda la vida.
Le apliqué `overflow-x: scroll;` a los estilos de tabla para que tenga scroll horizontal y `position: absolute;` a la clase "pinned" para que tus primeras celdas esten siempre visibles.

Si tienes alguna duda con el código, estaré agradecido de responderte.

Answer (score -1):

Intenta con esto:

```css
.table-prueba {
  overflow-x: auto;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left:100px;
}


#prueba {
   position: absolute;
    background-color: #b5c8ca;
      margin-left:-100px;

}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <div class="table-prueba">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col" id="prueba">Columna1</div>
                <div class="col">Columna2</div>
                <div class="col">Columna3</div>
                <div class="col">Columna4</div>
                <div class="col">Columna5</div>
                <div class="col">Columna6</div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Checate [este ejemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/cfr94p3w/) en fiddle, está genial, creo es justo lo que buscas :)

Comment: Te invito a leer [answer], si bien el aporte puede solucionar el problema, una explicación al código siempre se agradece